# mysql-workbench installation error

Tags: mysql

I have ubuntu 14.04 and try to install mysql-workbench.
and getting an error as

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
mysql-workbench: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.0.8+dfsg-2) but 6.0.8+dfsg-2 is to be installed
```

as i know it looks like a required dependencies to run mysql-workbench properly. but how can i install these dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. the proble was that mysql-workbench depends on mysql-client, which is currently at 5.5, so it won't install with mysql-server 5.6 installed.

So for avoiding the unmet dependencies problem We are not going to install MySQL Workbench from apt-get, instead, we are going to download and install its binary distribution.

**Stpe 1. Download**

Go to MySQL Workbench downloads page, select Ubuntu Linux as your platform and download the right version for your Ubuntu.

**Step 2. Installation**

Once you’ve downloaded the .deb file, all you need to to is double click on it and the Ubuntu Software Center will open. If MySQL Workbench doesn’t start the installation automatically, click on Install button and wait for the process complete.

And you are done! You have the latest version of MySQL Workbench running on your MySQL Server 5.6